# Send RestKit logs to Crashlytics

Tags: ios, restkit, crashlytics

If I understand correctly then using CLSNSLog instead of NSLog will also send logs (which I see in the console while developing) to the Crashlytics log report. Sounds perfect.

What would be even more perfect, is that all output that I get in console would be sent to Crashlytics.
More preciscly ... RestKit currently logs network requests like this:

> I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:174 GET 'https://api.domain.com/api/...'
>
> I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:210 GET 'https://api.domain.com/api/...' (200 OK) [1.3199 s]

Is there a way to include RestKit logging also in the Crashlytics Logs ?

This would give me a perfect trace (what I see in the console log while debugging/developing is in my opinion the best trace possible since I am used to the output sequence) that would later help me identify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I want to encourage you to log everything over the network to crashalytics, because I'd say it's a much better idea to log to a local file, rolling the contents so you never have more than a few hundred lines, and only upload following a crash.

That said, RestKit uses LibComponentLogging, so you can find configuration details [here](http://0xc0.de/LibComponentLogging#Crashlytics).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.

I agree. But isn't Crashlytics already doing this for me? Only sending  last X lines of log and doing this only when app crashes ?

Comment: @nej As I checked before, the Crashlytics logs are a rolling 64 KB using FIFO.